# populate IDataReader without reflection using any (specified) object Collection

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, collections, sqldatareader

I struggling to get something done when it suppose to be very easy to implement

say I have a car object

```
public class tblCarObj
{
    public String Model;
    public Int32 Year;
}
```

within these lines there is an implementation of `reflection` that is based on the fact that the object members are unknown (is this the only reason?)

which is nice for a generic functionality, but I am sacrificing functionality for performance if needed. and I wonder why both Links (see below) uses this approach.

can I simply use `MyCarReader<tblCarObj>`

instead of

```
    //for this instance.        
    private IEnumerator<T> enumerator = null;

    //List of all public fields in <T>
    private List<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>();

    public MyGenericDataReader(IEnumerable<T> enumerator)
    {
        this.enumerator = enumerator.GetEnumerator();            

        //Find the enumerator of all public fields
        foreach (FieldInfo fieldinfo in typeof(T).GetFields(                
            BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            fields.Add(fieldinfo);
        }
    }
```

**is there a way to implement this method without the use of reflection ?**

background

the task Is to simply upload a collection of objects into database table,

```
List<tblCarObj>
```

where:

- DataBase Table is Ready
- DataBase Table matches the DataObject members
- both are known at compile time.

and directly use it on `SQLBulckCopy` instead of a more complex object such as  `DataTable`

- [MyGenericDataReader.cs](http://technico.qnownow.com/custom-data-reader-to-bulk-copy-data-from-object-collection-to-sql-server/)
- [GenericListDataReader.cs](http://www.csvreader.com/posts/GenericListDataReader.cs)

Comment: I think it uses reflection, but [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) is a pre-built library that does exactly what you are looking for. It is developed by the people at StackOverflow and is used as the backend for this very site.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the question is why if I am willing to just tell it to take a list of initialized objects why do you need Dapper ? why reflection what am I missing here ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, sorry.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I want to populate an `SqlDataReader`, I can do it with `IDataReader`, we can see how in those examples, it should be less complex if you feed it with `new List<aknownInitializedObject>` instead of generic that has to use reflection as it does not know the members but I do supply it

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I just want to change it to use specific object and specify the members instead of using reflection or any other getmember as I don't ask from it to get members I want give it  so I could save the overhead , just type it fileds - objectfields  here they are just use them

Comment: @ScottChamberlain please review my answer as i am making it clearer now. if there's any thing to change or make sure there will be no major accidents  as it is ... please do comment it.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the runtime and the compiler to do something that it cannot do without reflecting over the type.

The information that allows the CLR and the compiler to know what properties are on the type are in the type's metadata. Reflection is the mechanism that queries metadata and serves it up in a meaningful way so that we can use it to discover the shape and content of a type. Without it, a type is essentially a named black box.

You *could* do what you want, but you'd have to code it by hand. The reason the libraries out there exist is because reflection makes it possible for you to avoid that extra work.

Comment: @JbobJohan Yes. How can I help you?

Answer (score 0):

needs further test to try

- eliminate unnecessary mappings **Update: tested ok**

(gain extra performance when `MyTestObject` properties/fields are same as columns)

- if making it generic will effect it only slightly the use it with `T`

  **using :**

  ```
  public string sqlCon ="data source=(local);Initial Catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=True";
  public SqlCommand Cmd;
  public SqlConnection Conn;
  public SqlDataReader Drdr;
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Conn = new SqlConnection(this.sqlCon);
      this.Cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [tblTestBC]", this.Conn);
      useBulkCopy();
  }
  void justread()
  {
      this.Cmd.Connection.Open();
      this.Drdr = this.Cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (this.Drdr.HasRows)
          while (this.Drdr.Read())
          {

          }
      this.Cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  void useBulkCopy()
  {
      var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(this.Cmd.Connection);
      bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblTestBC";
      //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("age", "age");
      //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
      this.Cmd.Connection.Open();
      try
      {

          using (var dataReader = new mySimpleDataReader())
          {
              bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
          }
          this.Cmd.Connection.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      }

  }
  ```

**GenericIdataReader**

```
namespace GenericIdataReader
{
    public class MyTestObject
    {
        public int age;
        public string name;
    }
    public class mySimpleDataReader : IDataReader
    {
        private IEnumerator<MyTestObject> enumerator = null;
        public List<MyTestObject> prpLst { get; set; }
        List<MyTestObject> lst()
        {
            var rt = new List<MyTestObject>(5);
            for (int i = 0; i < rt.Capacity; i++)
            {
                var tmp = new MyTestObject { age = i, name = "MyTestObject->"+i };
                rt.Add(tmp);
            }
            return rt;
        }
        public mySimpleDataReader()
        {
            this.prpLst = this.lst();
            this.enumerator = this.prpLst.GetEnumerator();            
        }


        public void Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Depth
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public DataTable GetSchemaTable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsClosed
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public bool NextResult()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Read()
        {
            return enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public int RecordsAffected
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.enumerator.Dispose();
        }

        public int FieldCount
        {
            get { return 2; }// must be setted 
        }

        public bool GetBoolean(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public byte GetByte(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public char GetChar(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IDataReader GetData(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetDataTypeName(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public decimal GetDecimal(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public double GetDouble(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Type GetFieldType(int i)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public float GetFloat(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Guid GetGuid(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public short GetInt16(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetInt32(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetInt64(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetName(int i)
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetOrdinal(string name)
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetString(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetValue(int i) // this is where data is being pooled
        {
            if (i > 0) return enumerator.Current.name;
// so need to create an object that will hold numeric index or simply change
//this to return an indexed object instead of an enumerator according to parmeter i value
            return enumerator.Current.age;
        }

        public int GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsDBNull(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public object this[int i]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

}
```